# search result for paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using Stored Procedure for a Search program.

Search result may be more than 10 records.

If I were to show the result of more than 10 records on page 1, 2 and 3 each.

Now if user click on 2 be like that again, do not complete the search

how can paging result without full search in any page 1,2,3?

if use session["search"]=datasource in first search and use future .now how can we access to session["search"] row 0,1,2;?

Comment: You will have to maintain the DataSource somewhere like in the session and bind it again in the page index changed event, this will not cause you to hit the database again. Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Except for the session can be used from another data source

Comment: Now Session["search"]=datasource; now how can access to row 0,1,...

Comment: It's very difficult to know the intention of the question Please check the grammer before posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly what you're asking. Here is a good thread on sql server paging though.

[SQL Server 2008 paging methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358253/sql-server-2008-paging-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Your question not very clear. Can't understand what you need. However if you are referring to paging in asp.net and c#, then the following tutorials may be of help:

[Efficiently Paging Through Large Amounts of Data](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs)

[Paging In ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135845/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091003-1.aspx)