# ROW_NUMBER() alternative

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table which contains:

```
ID      ID_TYPE
---------------   
 1        0
 2        1
 3        1
```

Now I want to get the current record number when performing:

```
SELECT ID
FROM IDTable
WHERE ID_TYPE = 1
```

I don't want to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ID] desc)`, because it's very slow when using larger tables.

What are my alternatives ?

Comment: "I don't want to use `ROW_NUMBER() ...` because it's very small when using larget tables" What? What does this even mean? Can you give an example of the problem you have?

Comment: I don't think the typo "larget" was the issue here...

Comment: Please explain in English what you are actually trying to do.  What is the purpose of your query?  That will help us determine the most efficient way of solving your problem.

Comment: I meant "slow". I typed too fast :).. sorry

Comment: What do you mean by 'current record'?

Comment: @dan1111 the purpose is to get the current enumeration number of the select. For instance: in the example above I want to get 1 for the first result, and 2 for the second result and so on..

Comment: If you are doing pagination, [you might find this article useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358253/sql-server-2008-paging-methods).

Comment: What makes you think that `ROW_NUMBER()` is slow? Can you show an example of a query that is fast without it but slows down when you add it? And you should include the execution plans for both queries, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as number from IDTable WHERE ID_TYPE = 1
```