# Sql Server Pagening with large amount of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this SQL query for pagination:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (
    SELECT T1.*,T2.*, ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY ID DESC) row 
    FROM 
        table1 t1
         LEFT JOIN 
        table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.pid
  ) tbl
WHERE row>= @start and row<@end
```

Now the problem is that the select result can be thousands of records, that will be executed for each page of each users.

Any suggestion that I can part the select (select less records?)

the ROW_NUMBER could be over order by ID or DATE.

and by the way, selecting * is just for simplicity of the sample code.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Do any of these answers help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358253/sql-server-2008-paging-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or above you can use the [Offset](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and [Fetch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms180152.aspx) keywords as stated [here](http://dbadiaries.com/new-t-sql-features-in-sql-server-2012-offset-and-fetch)

Comment: as written in the comments he does not;)

Comment: well I might be able to use sql server 2012, the performance is my first priority