# Dynamic SQL Optimal Paging

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, paging

For several years, I've been creating my dynamic sql paging by wrapping it into a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER`().  This method has been mentionned sevral times in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4359183/315493) and it offer good performance.

However, since sql server 2012 has introduced `offset` and `fetch` with even better performance, I decided to see if I could optimize my sql 2008 R2 paging statement to match sql server 2012 performance.

This [blog entry](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2012/04/26/offset-without-offset.aspx) describe a very interesting alternative to the `offset` command:

```
WITH cteKeySeek
AS
(
SELECT 
       BusinessEntityID,
       LastName,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastName,BusinessEntityID)-1 AS RowN
  FROM Person.Person
)
SELECT 
      TOP(20) cteKeySeek.LastName,
      FirstName,
      cteKeySeek.BusinessEntityID,
      RowN
 FROM cteKeySeek
 INNER LOOP JOIN Person.Person   
 ON cteKeySeek.BusinessEntityID = Person.BusinessEntityID
 WHERE RowN >= 20 AND RowN<=39
 ORDER BY LastName,BusinessEntityID;
```

However, this alternative mentioned above is using an indexed table while my needs are for dynamic sql.  I tried several way to create a similar implementation for a dynamic sql statement without success... the performance is  10x slower than the regular CTE / ROW_NUMBERS method.

Here's the best implementation I could create so far:

```
WITH T1 AS ( << Your Dynamic SQL here >>  )
SELECT TOP 100 T2.RowN , T2.*
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY WhateverField ) AS RowN, WhateverID, WhateverField
  FROM T1
) AS T2
INNER LOOP JOIN T1 ON T2.WhateverID  = T1.WhateverID 
WHERE T2.RowN BETWEEN 10000 AND 10999
ORDER BY WhateverField;
```

Ideally, I would prefer a solution that would involve dynamic sql only... I know sometime storedproc may offer other alternatives but if I have to choose between managing SP and migrating to SQL 2012, I'd go with the second option.