# How to get elements from table by row number in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table in my database containing about 100000 records. I have to select 10 records from it by row number from n to n+10. I have used following way to get records-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE getGalleryImagesByPaging
@startIndex int,
@endIndex int
AS
  BEGIN
  WITH gallery as(
   Select ImageId,Caption, ROW_NUMBER() over (Order by id desc) as RN from   imagegalleries where ishome=1 and IsActive=1 
)
Select ImageId, Caption From gallery Where RN Between @startIndex AND @endIndex;
  END
GO
```

but I think it is very expensive query because it selects all the elements first then select records by row number. Please suggest me the better way to do it.

Comment: Post also the structure  of `dbo.imagegalleries` and list of indexes.

Comment: yes but it is not auto incremented.

Comment: dbo.imagegalleries contains columns named- Id, ImageId, Caption. Id is not auto incremented. My problem is not specific to this case only. This type of problem occurs in many tables in my scenario.

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968168/sql-server-using-union-all-for-multiple-tables-then-paging-implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `OFFSET` `FETCH` to get your desire output in `Sql server 2012 and +`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE getGalleryImagesByPaging
@startIndex int,
@endIndex int
AS
BEGIN
Select ImageId,
       Caption 
       from   imagegalleries 
       where ishome=1 and IsActive=1 
       ORDER BY id desc OFFSET @startIndex ROWS FETCH NEXT @endIndex ROWS ONLY
END
GO
```

**Limitations in Using OFFSET-FETCH**

- ORDER BY is mandatory to use OFFSET and FETCH clause.
- OFFSET clause is mandatory with FETCH. You can never use, ORDER BY …
  FETCH.
- TOP cannot be combined with OFFSET and FETCH in the same query
  expression.
- The OFFSET/FETCH rowcount expression can be any arithmetic, constant,
  or parameter expression that will return an integer value. The
  rowcount expression does not support scalar sub-queries.

**Reference:** **[MSDN => OFFSET and FETCH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)**

Comment: Do mention that it will work with **Sql server 2012+**