# "paging" SELECT SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, pagination

I have a table with 100 rows, and want to SELECT just a part of them(for example from row 20 to 30), like "paging" the SELECT.

which is an efficient way to do that in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190/how-to-return-a-page-of-results-from-sql

Comment: sql server 2008 r2, i found a bit of things, but those don't seems to be the best ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it like this (assuming your table is called "tablename" ,your primary key is id, and you want rows 10 to 15).

```
select * from 
(select *,row_number() over (order by id) as r from tablename)
t where r >10 and r < 15;
```

it may look inefficient but this is (sort of) how its done internally in linq.

Comment: seems to be the same algorithm than [How to return a page of results from SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190/how-to-return-a-page-of-results-from-sql) thank you.