# SQL Server 2012 - How to display certain number of records on a single page?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, pagination

I am new to C# and SQL Server. I have created a SQL Server database and a C# application. The C# application works well and retrieves all records when I use this statement:

```
SELEC * FROM tableName
```

and wWhen I use this statement

```
SELEC TOP 10 * FROM tableName
```

it displays the top 10 results only.

Now I want to display the next 10 results, when I click on a `Next` button. I have tried it and searched online, but didn't find a solution. Please let me know how can I do this. I need the exact SQL query which can retrieve the results from row M upto row N.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search for pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Muhammad Suhail you should use and search for paging.
Just create a store procedure, when click on next button pass a pagenumber and pageSize to an sql store procedure. Following example is the best way to create paging in sql server store proedure.

Only you should pass parameter `@pageSize` and `@pageNumber`
This script is use `NorthWind` db
Just change the `@pageNumber` and see your pages

```
DECLARE  @pageNumber int=4
DECLARE  @pageSize int=3  

  SELECT EmployeeID,LastName,FirstName  
  FROM(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeID) AS Row,
        EmployeeID,
        LastName,
        FirstName
        FROM dbo.Employees
    ) AS EmployeRecords
  WHERE
  Row BETWEEN (@pageSize*(@pageNumber-1)+1) AND @pageNumber * @pageSize
```

when `@pageSize`=3 and `@pageNumber=1`

[image]

when `@pageSize`=3 and `@pageNumber=2`

[image]

And so on.....................

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I am using sql 2012, and there is a new feature in it, that is OFFSET...FETCH, that I have found a few minutes ago. I think that is better than this long process? What do you say about this?

Comment: I am not still use sql 2012, if u found some good way thats best.. thanks. But above is the best way for paging if there no new feature... like you mention OFFSET FETCH etc. thanks for sharing i will study these features..

Answer (score 0):

Inner query adds RowIndex which is automatic number per row where the rows are ordered by columnToOrderBy, the outer query just uses that new row to filter out the rows you don't want on the page by passing the start and end row values to the BETWEEN clause: i.e. the number of the first row and the number of the last one (inclusive)

```
select * from (
    select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by columnToOrderBy) as RowIndex
          , * 
    from    TableInQuestion) t
where RowIndex Between 10 and 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this discussion, it has all the info you need:

[How to return a page of results from SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190/how-to-return-a-page-of-results-from-sql)

Another option would be to start using LINQ. Then you can use something like this:

`Where(query your data).Skip(x).Take(y);`

This approach is also discussed in the above mentioned thread.