# How to paginate Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dataexplorer

Using [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/875322) to create queries:

```
SELECT P.id, creationdate,tags,owneruserid,answercount
--SELECT DISTINCT TAGNAME ,TAGID
FROM TAGS  AS T
JOIN POSTTAGS AS PT
ON T.ID = PT.TAGID
JOIN POSTS AS P
ON PT.POSTID = P.ID
--WHERE CAST(P.TAGS AS VARCHAR) IN('JAVA')
WHERE PT.TAGID = 3143
```

How is it possible to add pagination in the query in order to take not only the first 50,000 results, but then run the query again to take the next remaining results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to "page" through TSQL results; see:

- [How to return a page of results from SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190/how-to-return-a-page-of-results-from-sql)
  and
- [SQL performance: WHERE vs WHERE(ROW_NUMBER)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212692/sql-performance-where-vs-whererow-number)

Here I will use the CTE method as:

- It uses convenient row numbers to page through results, rather than trying to track less predictable factors such as `creationdate`.
- It reportedly performs faster than the `OFFSET` method.

So, that question's query becomes [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/887590/paging-through-large-data-sets?StartRow=1&EndRow=50000):

```
-- StartRow: Starting row for paging
-- EndRow: Ending row for paging (Max 50K rows at a time)
WITH allData AS (
    SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.creationdate) AS row
                , P.id
                , P.creationdate
                , P.tags
                , P.owneruserid
                , P.answercount
    FROM        Posttags    AS PT
    JOIN        Posts       AS P    ON PT.postid = P.id
    WHERE       PT.tagid    = 3143  -- tag [scala]
)
SELECT      *
FROM        allData
WHERE       row    >= ##StartRow:INT?1##
AND         row    <= ##EndRow:INT?50000##
ORDER BY    row
```

Comment: Super useful! I tweaked this to make it a bit faster and easier to use by 1) removing the condition `row    <= ##EndRow:INT?50000##` and 2) changing the first condition to `row    >= 1 + 50000*(##StartRow:INT?1## - 1)` so that my inputs can be 1, 2, 3, ... instead of 1, 50001, 100001, ...