# How to get ALL users' posts' tags (include answer's tags) in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, dataexplorer

I use a query in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=popular) (SEDE).

This is [my query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/901423?UserId=331508):

```
SELECT A.Id
       , A.PostTypeId
       , A.Title
       , A.Body
       , A.ParentId
       , A.Tags
       , A.CreationDate
FROM   posts A
       LEFT JOIN users U
              ON A.OwnerUserId = U.id
WHERE  U.Id = ##UserId##
       AND A.PostTypeId = 1
UNION
SELECT A.Id
       , A.PostTypeId
       , A.Title
       , A.Body
       , A.ParentId
       , B.Tags
       , A.CreationDate
FROM   posts A
       LEFT JOIN users U
              ON A.OwnerUserId = U.id
       RIGHT JOIN posts B
               ON A.ParentId = B.Id
WHERE  U.Id = ##UserId##
       AND A.PostTypeId = 2
```

In the code above, posts in Stack Overflow have 2 types: question and answer. Questions(`PostTypeId` is 1 in database schema) have the tags, but the answers(`PostTypeId` is 2 in database schema) do not have the tags.
Answers belong to questions through the `ParentId`.

But the efficiency of the my query above is too low, I only can get some (using user id) posts' tags.

How can I get all users' posts' tags within the SEDE time out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. **You cannot get  all users' posts' tags.**  Currently, [there are over 41 million posts](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) and [SEDE limits results to 50,000 rows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213050/why-cant-i-pull-in-all-the-so-users-from-data-explorer).
2. So, you need to: (A) **restrict the results somehow** or (B) [page through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884419/how-to-paginate-stack-exchange-data-explorer-sede-results) 41 M posts, 50K at a time (NOT RECOMMENDED), or (C) use [the Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) or [Google's BigQuery($)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/15/you-can-now-play-with-stack-overflow-data-on-googles-bigquery/) instead.
3. If you are not going to pull anything from the `Users` table but ID, then don't include that table.  It chews up cycles and `Posts.OwnerUserId` is the same thing.
4. Avoid `UNION` statements if possible (it is in this case).
5. If using `UNION` statements, use `UNION ALL` if possible (it is in this case). This saves the engine from having to do duplicate checks.

So, here is the **execution plan for the original query:**

[image: before]

Here is **a streamlined plan:**

[image]

And [the query that corresponds to it](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/901398/see-https-stackoverflow-com-q-52464385?UserId=9522078):

```
SELECT      TOP 50000
            p.OwnerUserId                                       AS [User]
            , p.Id                                              AS [Post Id]
            , CASE WHEN p.PostTypeId = 1 THEN 'Q' ELSE 'A' END  AS [Type]
            , COALESCE (p.Title, ownr.Title)                    AS [Title]
            , p.Body
            , COALESCE (p.Tags, ownr.Tags)                      AS [Tags]
            , p.CreationDate
FROM        Posts p
LEFT JOIN   Posts ownr      ON ownr.ID = p.ParentId
WHERE       p.OwnerUserId   = ##UserId##
AND         p.PostTypeId    IN (1, 2)  -- Question, answer
ORDER BY    p.OwnerUserId DESC,  p.CreationDate
```

-- which also gives more readable results -- especially when the `WHERE` clause is removed.

But, if you can limit by, say, user before hand; you get an even [more efficient query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/901422/posts-with-tags-for-prefiltered-users):

```
WITH usersOfInterest AS (
    SELECT      TOP 10
                u.Id                                                AS [UserId]
                , u.DisplayName
    FROM        Users u
    ORDER BY    u.Reputation DESC
)
SELECT      
            [User] = 'site://u/' + CAST(u.UserId AS NVARCHAR) + '|' + CAST(u.UserId AS NVARCHAR)
            , p.Id                                              AS [Post Id]
            , CASE WHEN p.PostTypeId = 1 THEN 'Q' ELSE 'A' END  AS [Type]
            , COALESCE (p.Title, ownr.Title)                    AS [Title]
            , p.Body
            , COALESCE (p.Tags, ownr.Tags)                      AS [Tags]
            , p.CreationDate
FROM        usersOfInterest u
INNER JOIN  Posts p         ON u.UserId = p.OwnerUserId
LEFT JOIN   Posts ownr      ON ownr.Id  = p.ParentId
WHERE       p.PostTypeId    IN (1, 2)   -- Question, answer
ORDER BY    u.UserId DESC,  p.CreationDate
```

(This query [adds a convenient hyperlink](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) to the user id.)

Note that just the top 10 users have more than 50K posts.