# Query to insert row number to paginate results

Tags: sql, column-alias

I try to execute a query which takes all data from a table. I would like to use pagination as their is a constration in the results. So I try to insert pagination in the query like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56890779)

What I tried is this

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY reputation) as row, *
From users
Where reputation > 1000000 AND  row >= ##StartRow:INT?1##
AND         row    <= ##EndRow:INT?50000##
ORDER BY    row
```

The error I receive is this:

> Invalid column name 'row'. Invalid column name 'row'.

What can I do?

Comment: Hi! Can you tag your choice of dbms and preferably your db version as well? I.e. Oracle, MySql, SQL Server, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your query up in a *derived table* (i.e. the subquery):

```
select * from
(
  Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY reputation) as row, *
  From users
  Where reputation > 1000000
) dt
where   row >= ##StartRow:INT?1##
  AND   row    <= ##EndRow:INT?50000##
ORDER BY    row
```

Note that `row` is a reserved word according to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard, so you may need to delimit that column name as `"row"`. (Or change it to something else.)