# ASP.Net: How to do pagination with a Repeater?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm using the Repeater control on my site to display data from the database. I need to do pagination ("now displaying page 1 of 10", 10 items per page, etc) but I'm not sure I'm going about it the best way possible.

I know the Repeater control doesn't have any built-in pagination, so I'll have to make my own. Is there a way to tell the DataSource control to return rows 10-20 of a much larger result set? If not, how do I write that into a query (SQL Server 2005)? I'm currently using the TOP keyword to only return the first 10 rows, but I'm not sure how to display rows 10-20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a way to page the data, but have you looked into the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) control? It gives the flexibility of repeater / data list but with built in paging like the grid view.

And for paging in sql, you would want to do something like [this](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/12/30/2652.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the PagedDataSource, it allows you to turn a standard data source into one that can be paged.  Here's an [example article](http://www.codeproject.com/Kb/aspnet/pagingBySreejith%20Thathanattu.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840/paging-sql-server-2005-results).