# What is the best method for paging with datagrid performance?

Tags: performance, datagrid, data-paging

On a site with a high number of users, should paging be handled in code, or with a stored procedure.  If you have employed caching, please include your success factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it at database level. Talking about sql server 2005, i would use the new ROW_NUMBER() function, look at:
[Paging SQL Server 2005 Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840/paging-sql-server-2005-results)

Where a typical sql would be:

```
SELECT Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY UserName) As RowID, UserFirstName, UserLastName
FROM Users
WHERE RowID Between 0 AND 9
```

Here https://web.archive.org/web/20210510021915/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx you can see how it works and examine a little benchmark by Scott Mitchell.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I never page stuff outside SQL Server. I do this at database level as if you have a million records to be paged, if you retrieve it in application layer and page it there, you are already paying a **huge** cost.

Answer (score 3):

99.9% of the time, paging should be done on your database server. However, stored procedures are not required to do this, and, in fact, many stored procedure solutions rely on cursors and are quite inefficient. Ideally, use a single SQL statement tailored to your database platform to retrieve just the records you need and no more.

Comment: Well, I'd have to disagree with the view that just because it uses a stored-proc it is any more likely to use a cursor... but the rest I agree with. If somebody is going to write bad SQL, they'll do it through any route available.

Comment: Agreed, "many" <> "more likely" - that was just a caveat against thinking an SP is necessarily faster. Perhaps it was heavy-handed in the context of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Most database vendors offer rich paging support at the database. Make use of it ;-p Note that it doesn't have to be a stored-procedure to do this (I'll sideline the ever-running stored-proc vs ad-hoc command debate).

As an aside, many frameworks will *also* do this for you efficiently. For example, in .NET 3.5 (with LINQ), you can use `Skip()` and `Take()` to do paging that is used at the db.

Answer (score 0):

I think ***It depends*** on number of records to be paged. For example you have 100 records to be paged I think there is no need SQL paging stuff to do this. I am always trying to keep in my mind KISS principle and Premature optimization.