# Paging in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

How I can implement paging in SQL Server database it has no LIMT keyword like mysql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paging SQL Server 2005 Results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840/paging-sql-server-2005-results)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `row_number()`

Comment: sorry, did not notice Tim's comment below

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't use LIMIT, but you can use TOP:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM foo
WHERE whateverPagingID >= 650 /* or whatever the last page started with */
ORDER BY pagingID;
```

Comment: This only gets the first page. You need to use the ROW_NUMBER function

Comment: Implicit in my answer was that you're keeping the last pagingID (650 in this case) and supplying it to the WHERE clause.  Sorry if it was unclear.