# Can I use LIMIT N,M on SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, limit

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT [id], [name]
FROM [dbo.test_db_002] t1
LEFT JOIN [dbo.test_db_003] t2 ON t1.[id] = t2.[itmid]
ORDER BY t2.[iid] ASC;
```

This seems very simple, but I can't figure it out. I need to add `LIMIT N,M` to it to retrieve M items from the N'th one, but I keep getting errors around 'limit' word. I tried putting that `LIMIT` clause everywhere I could inside the sql statement above with no avail.

PS. I'm writing for SQL Server that comes with VS2010.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840/paging-sql-server-2005-results

Comment: Will values for N and M be static or variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548475/efficient-way-to-implement-paging

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358253/sql-server-2008-paging-methods

Comment: if you are willing to wait for denali you get https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/10/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-the-offset-clause-paging

Comment: Oh wow. N and M will be dynamic values that will be put into this SQL as numbers by ASP.NET script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer for your query, you may want: (depending on your values for `M` and `N`)

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT [id], [name], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.[iid] ASC) AS rowNumber
   FROM [dbo.test_db_002] t1
   LEFT JOIN [dbo.test_db_003] t2 ON t1.[id] = t2.[itmid]
)
SELECT [id], [name]
FROM cte
WHERE rowNumber BETWEEN 3 AND 5
```

Something to watch out for, the values in the between are `BETWEEN N AND N + M`

Also, here's a link with information about [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) which is the `WITH cte` syntax I used.

Comment: Jesus Christ! No wonder I have no hair left after trying to come up with this myself )) Let me try it out...

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct equivalent to `LIMIT N,M` in SQL Server, but you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) as row FROM MyTable) a
WHERE row > 5 and row <= 10
```

See here for some more info: ["LIMIT" in SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserver/archive/2006/10/25/limit-in-sql-server.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use all that "monstrosity" in my query? (Sorry, for calling your code that -- I'm actually referring to SQL Server....)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Row_Number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

example:

```
select * from 
(
  select cola, colb, row_number() over (order by col1 desc) as row
  from table ) x
where row between value1 and value2
```

Comment: While "use `ROW_NUMBER`" is the correct answer, your example won't work on SQL Server. You need to use a sub-query or CTE, as shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Limit with offset in sql server 2012:

```
SELECT email FROM myTable
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

//offset - no. of skipped rows

//next - required no. of next rows